# mysql: how to escape parenthesis in perl string

Tags: mysql, regex, perl, escaping, parentheses

I need to do a MySQL query using regex and part of the criteria contains parenthesis.
I know how to escape parenthesis in MySQL ... by using dual backslash.
But this does not seem to work when I put the query in a string to be used in perl.
I've tried enclosing the string in apostrophe, and tried again using quotes to no avail.
example:

```
select * from table where fieldname regexp '.\\(.';
```

The above works from MySQL but gives me error in perl:  "parentheses not balanced"

Comment: Can you put in your Perl code where you make the database call?

Comment: @XiVix you need to format the code for the dual backslash to show up, see how i edited your question :) in general it is always better to format actual code like this instead of placing it into the text.

Comment: You need to show your Perl code, since that appears to be the problem area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine that error would be obtained if you passed

```
select * from table where fieldname regexp '.\(.';
```

instead of

```
select * from table where fieldname regexp '.\\(.';
```

Are you sure you built your string correctly? I suspect you actually built the former strings.

For example, the code

```
"select * from table where fieldname regexp '.\\(.';"
```

produces the undesirable string

```
select * from table where fieldname regexp '.\(.';
```

while the code

```
"select * from table where fieldname regexp '.\\\\(.';"
```

produces the desired string

```
select * from table where fieldname regexp '.\\(.';
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easiest to use DBI's `quote` to safely interpolate variables into SQL strings, if you are working with naked SQL (note the common convention is to use a SQL interface of some sort, instead, for a whole slew of reasons which escape the scope of this answer).

So the quick/convenient way to achieve what you want is this:

```
#Assume $dbi is a handle to your database.
my $reg = $dbh->quote(".\\(.");
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from mailone where msub regexp $reg limit 1");
```